# How to silence QGIS 3 nightly build's debug output with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

When I run the following file `sample.py` it prints more than 100 lines of debug output. When porting a PyQGIS script to QGIS 3 it is hard to find the expected log statements in between all debug messages.

```
import os
from qgis.core import *

os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "offscreen"

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", False)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

print(qgs.qgisSettingsDirPath())

qgs.exitQgis()
```

(Run with `python3 sample.py` on a nightly installation.)

How can the output be made more readable and the debugging silenced?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the debug messages are not needed, especially when porting a Python script to QGIS 3. As they are coming through Qt methods they can be influenced with Qt settings (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html).

The environment variable QT_LOGGING_RULES specifies what to do with a specific log level:

```
user@qgisnightly:~$  export QT_LOGGING_RULES="*.debug=false" && python3 sample.py
/home/user/.local/share/profiles/default/
user@qgisnightly:~$ `
```

Future versions of Qt will even allow to specify multiple rules separated with a semicolon.